# summing rows in multi-index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with a multiindex

```
             A         B
year  age  
1895   0     10        12
1895   1     13        14
...
1965   0     34        45
1965   1     41        34
      ...
1965  50     56        22
1966   0     10        34
...
```

I would like to get all ages between two values (e.g. 10 and 20) summed for column A (and B). I played around a bit with .xs e.g.

```
pops.xs(20, level='age')
```

gives all the age 20 for each year, but I cannot get this for multiple ages (and summed).

Eg. for 0 and 1 I would like to get

Any suggetions for an elegant (efficient) way to do that?

```
          A         B
year    
1895      23        26
...
1965      75        79
...
```

Comment: `df.sum(level=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for select with `sum` per first level `year`s:

```
print (df)
           A   B
year age        
1895 8    10  12
     12   13  14
1965 0    34  45
     14   41  34
     12   56  22
1966 0    10  34

df = df.query('10 <= age <= 20').sum(level=0)
print (df)
       A   B
year        
1895  13  14
1965  97  56
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.query('10 <= age <= 20'))
           A   B
year age        
1895 12   13  14
1965 14   41  34
     12   56  22
```

Another solution is use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) for `index` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
i = df.index.get_level_values('age')
print (i)
Int64Index([8, 12, 0, 14, 12, 0], dtype='int64', name='age')

df = df[(i >= 10) & (i <= 20)].sum(level=0)
print (df)
       A   B
year        
1895  13  14
1965  97  56
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `loc` and `slice` to select the part of the DF you want such as:

```
df.loc[(slice(None),slice(10,20)),:].sum(level=0)
```

where `(slice(None),slice(10,20))` allows you to keep all indexes for all years and age between 10 and 20 included